# Float to string in Golang with a minimum width

Tags: go

I'm trying to get a float to print using fmt.Printf with a minimum width of 3

```
fmt.Printf("%3f", float64(0))
```

Should print `0.00`, but it instead prints `0.000000`
If I set the precision to 3, it truncates the value.

Basically, what I want is if the value is 0, it should print `0.00`. If the value is `0.045`, it should print `0.045`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function should do what you want:

```
func Float2String(i float64) string {
    // First see if we have 2 or fewer significant decimal places,
    // and if so, return the number with up to 2 trailing 0s.
    if i*100 == math.Floor(i*100) {
        return strconv.FormatFloat(i, 'f', 2, 64)
    }
    // Otherwise, just format normally, using the minimum number of
    // necessary digits.
    return strconv.FormatFloat(i, 'f', -1, 64)
}
```

Comment: I want it to print a minimum of 2 places after the decimal point, but it will have the precision to print the whole value.

Comment: Yep, that exactly

Answer (score 3):

Use [`strconv.FormatFloat`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatFloat), for example, like this:

https://play.golang.org/p/wNe3b6d7p0

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strconv.FormatFloat(0, 'f', 2, 64))
    fmt.Println(strconv.FormatFloat(0.0000003, 'f', -1, 64))
}
```

> 0.00
>   0.0000003

See the linked documentation for other formatting options and modes.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a dot

```
fmt.Printf("%.3f", float64(0))
```

will print out: 0.000

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/n6Goz3ULcm

Comment: This truncates the value.